# MySQL, Table with two dates?

Tags: mysql, database, timestamp, mysql-error-1067

I have a table, Where i need both firstmod and lastmod

firstmod needs to be the timestamp of then the row was created.
lastmod needs to update its self to the current time.

This is what i have so far..

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `SiteGen_JamesM_Live`.`PAGES` (
  `ID` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `USER_ID` INT(11) NOT NULL ,
  `TITLE` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL ,
  `HTML` LONGTEXT NOT NULL ,
  `FIRSTMOD` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 ,
  `LASTMOD` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`) )
ENGINE = InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT = 5
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = latin1
```

And this is what i get in return:

```
Executing SQL script in server
ERROR: Error 1067: Invalid default value for 'FIRSTMOD'
```

Comment: I don't know method Paul suggests, but I doubt it will work. '0000-00-00 00:00:00' is not a valid default value for a timestamp (since it starts from '1970-01-01 00:00:00'). You can try using 0 instead, but it will just do nothing.

Comment: Possibly because of this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_allow_invalid_dates
I still think it won't work.

Comment: How do i claim my questions from when not logged in?

Answer (score 0):

I'll run the risk of answering even though I'm not that familiar with MySQL.

I assume that the lastmod column should be defined:

```
 `LASTMOD` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ,
```

without the DEFAULT specify.  It's default will come through the ON UPDATE clause.

EDIT:

Oops, shouldn't risk these things.  From the manual:

> It is not possible to have the
>   current timestamp be the default value
>   for one column and the auto-update
>   value for another column.

Comment: Thanks, did not work and is confusing.. i would +1 for attempt if signed up. :)

Comment: MySQL man pages show DEFAULT 0 as the proper usage, and require a flag allowing 0 dates in the database.  Alternatively, you could use a real date there.

Answer (score 0):

There can be only one column with `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` in a table. You have to choose, whether it will be the one with DEFAULT (on insert) or one with ON UPDATE (or you can have both modifiers, but in one column).

There is a trick to have both, but since it's undocumented, it's also unreliable (actually I'm not sure if it still works).

See more here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/timestamp.html

> For one TIMESTAMP column in a table,
>   you can assign the current timestamp
>   as the default value and the
>   auto-update value. It is possible to
>   have the current timestamp be the
>   default value for initializing the
>   column, for the auto-update value, or
>   both. It is not possible to have the
>   current timestamp be the default value
>   for one column and the auto-update
>   value for another column

As a workaround, you could use a BEFORE INSERT or BEFORE UPDATE trigger to set one of these values.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
`FIRSTMOD` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' ,
`LASTMOD` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ,
```

and then in your inserts

```
INSERT INTO PAGES (FIRSTMOD, LASTMOD) VALUES (NULL, NULL)
```

The FIRSTMOD column should get a valid timestamp on insert and the LASTMOD should auto update thereafter.

Comment: Yes it should.  There are a bunch of useful comments at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/timestamp.html and also some alternate suggestions including the use of triggers to do the updates (which is a little more work to set up but then doesn't require passing NULL to those fields in the INSERT).

Comment: um, sorry I think it should be DEFAULT 0 for FIRSTMOD to use this technique.

Comment: I just ran this in my local mysql (version 5.1.23 on osx): CREATE TABLE test ( id INT DEFAULT 0, `FIRSTMOD` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 , `LASTMOD` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ); INSERT INTO test (FIRSTMOD, LASTMOD) VALUES (NULL,NULL); then I waited a moment and ran UPDATE test SET id = 1; SELECT * FROM test;  The result was |    1 | 2011-01-07 09:55:06 | 2011-01-07 09:55:18 |  ... works for me, perhaps it is the version of mysql that you are using?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `PAGES` (
  `ID` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `USER_ID` INT(11) NOT NULL ,
  `TITLE` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL ,
  `HTML` LONGTEXT NOT NULL ,
  `FIRSTMOD` datetime NOT NULL,  
  `LASTMOD` TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`) )
ENGINE = InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT = 5
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = latin1
```

and set up a trigger to update FIRSTMOD on insert

```
Create Trigger Insert_PAGES
  After INSERT On PAGES
  For Each Row
  Begin
   set new.FIRSTMOD = now();
  End
```

This will set the time of **firstmod** = now() when the record is created
and **lastmod**  will update its self to the current time when ever changes are made to the record